# How to move forward an object in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a game object and attached a script to it. I need to rotate and move the object in a straight line, depending on the rotation. I made a turn, but I have problems with movement. Any solutions?

```
    //Rotation
    if (Input.GetAxis("Rotation") > 0) {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.back, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        
    }
    else if (Input.GetAxis("Rotation") < 0)
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.back, -turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        
    }

    //Velocity
    if (Input.GetAxis("Thrust") != 0) {
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * Speed);
        }
    else if (Input.GetAxis("Thrust") <= 0.1f){
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code as text rather than as an image.

Comment: What actual problem with the movement are you getting?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

`Rigidbody.AddForce` applies the vector as force in world space. So, you need to give it a vector that is in the world space direction of the transform's forward. Luckily, that's as simple as using [`transform.forward`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html), `transform.up`, or `transform.right` or a negation of one of them instead of `Vector3.forward`:

```
//Rotation
if (Input.GetAxis("Rotation") > 0) {
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.back, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    
}
else if (Input.GetAxis("Rotation") < 0)
{
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.back, -turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    
}

//Velocity
if (Input.GetAxis("Thrust") != 0) {
        Vector3 frontDirection;
        
        // probably one of these for a 2D game:
        frontDirection = transform.right;
        //frontDirection = -transform.right;
        //frontDirection = transform.up;
        //frontDirection = -transform.up;

        rb.AddForce(frontDirection * Time.deltaTime * Speed);
    }
else if (Input.GetAxis("Thrust") <= 0.1f){
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: A game object moves on z axis. That's why i can't move it on 2d project.

Comment: The Z axis is the forward of the object. If that's not what you want, then you don't want to move it forward, you'll be wanting to move it up, down, left, or right. Your question says "forward" but it really should say a different direction, so please update the question. An image of the local axes of the object and an explanation of which part of the object is the "front" would suffice.

Comment: @RomanZhykhor I included a part in my answer where you can use trial and error to figure out which direction to use